# Symbolic Integration gives wrong answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have tried to integrate the following expression in Mathematica 10.1

```
Integrate[x^m (1 - x)^i, {x, p, 1}, Assumptions -> 1 > p > 0 && i > -1]

(*Out[1]=-Beta[p, 1 + m, 1 + i] + (Gamma[1 + i] Gamma[1 + m])/Gamma[2 + i + m]*)
```

Which is incorrect for m ≤−1:

```
-Beta[p, 1 + m, 1 + i] + (Gamma[1 + i] Gamma[1 + m])/Gamma[2 + i + m] /. m -> -1

(*Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
Out[2]=Indeterminate*)
```

While

```
Block[{p = 0.1, m = -1, i = 1}, 
  Integrate[x^m (1 - x)^i, {x, p, 1}]
]
(*Out[3]=1.40259*)
```

Gives real answer.

So the problem is that Mathematica represents the answer using [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) which is actually approaching  infinity when m approaches -1. At the same time the original integral value stays finite since p>0.

While I understand where and why Mathematica makes a mistake, I would like to know

1. How can I get the correct symbolic result using Mathematica?
2. How to avoid this kind of errors in future?

Comment: You did not show that the result is incorrect for `m<-1`. Moreover some numeric tests work out just fine e.g. `m->-11/10,p->2/5,i->33/10}`. I think that earns a close vote.

Comment: I did test only for some integer m. Your example shows me that I don't understand something. Beta function definition is  https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/8/6/786625156bba2f88513d20cf266c7ec0.png and for m ≤-1 it has to give infinity, isn't that right? With non integer m I get finite answer like you did.

Comment: You are getting indeterminate forms when substituting negative integers. In principle one could get better results by taking limits. But I don't think `Limit` will handle these.

Comment: The question is why only integer?

If I try to evaluate **Beta[0.1,-0.2,3]** using its mathematical definition
`Integrate[x^(-1.2) (1 - x)^2, {x, 0, 0.1}]` I get infinity. trying to evaluate  `N@Beta[0.1, -0.2, 3]` gives finite answer instead.

Comment: That's not the definition everywhere. Analytic continuation takes it outside the range where the integral works. See the [functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/02/01/).

Comment: Okay now I see what is happening. Beta function for negative arguments is defined by it's connection with Gamma-function. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica gives generic answers, and you will need to handle the singularity at m=-1 as a separate case. Even simpler than your example is:

```
Integrate[x^m, x]

x^(1 + m)/(1 + m)
```

If you then evaluate at m=-1 you also get infinity

```
Integrate[x^m, x]//.m->-1
```

Note that the generic answer holds for all m not equal to -1. The answer is correct for $m \neq -1$. For example,

```
Block[{p = 0.1, m = -1.1, i = 1}, Integrate[x^m (1 - x)^i, {x, p, 1}]]
```

and

```
-Beta[p, 1 + m, 1 + i] + (Gamma[1 + i] Gamma[1 + m])/Gamma[2 + i + m] /. {m -> -1.1, p -> 0.1, i -> 1}
```

both return the same answer: 1.61802

Comment: It gives incorrect answer for any m≤1, not only m=-1 (see the definition of beta function).=

Comment: It gives the same answer for the case you suggest with p = 0.1, m = -1.1, i = 1